# SQL insert into select from - insert the id instead of the data

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, fact-table

I need to populate my fact table with data from `lds_placement` table. I have selected the records and here is what it looks like:

```
fk1_account_id | fk3_job_role_id | salary | no_of_placements |  YEAR
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     10        |        3        | 165000 |        5         |  2010
     10        |        3        | 132000 |        4         |  2011
     10        |        3        | 132000 |        4         |  2012
     20        |        2        | 990000 |        3         |  2010
     20        |        2        | 132000 |        2         |  2011
     20        |        2        | 132000 |        2         |  2012
```

I want to insert `time_id` from a different table called `time_dim` into the column `year` and not the actual year itself.

The `time_dim` table looks like this:

```
time_id | year
---------------
   5    | 2015
   1    | 2013
   2    | 2010
   3    | 2014
   4    | 2012
   6    | 2011
```

I need to insert into "year" column is actually:

```
year
 2
 6
 4
 2
 6
 4
```

Please give me the way to insert `time_id` instead of `year` in the table. 
Here is the code I used to select the top-most table.

```
SELECT
     fk1_account_id,
     fk3_job_role_id,
     Sum(actual_salary)                             AS salary,
     Count(1)                                       AS no_of_placements,
     MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM plt_estimated_end_date)) AS year
  FROM lds_placement
 GROUP BY fk1_account_id, fk3_job_role_id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM plt_estimated_end_date)
 ORDER BY fk1_account_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left join` if you want to capture records where `year` doesn't exist in `time_dim`. Else use `inner_join`.

```
select t.fk1_account_id,t.fk3_job_role_id,t.salary,t.no_of_placements
,d.time_id 
from 
(SELECT fk1_account_id, fk3_job_role_id, Sum(actual_salary) as salary, Count(1) as no_of_placements, MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM plt_estimated_end_date)) AS YEAR 
FROM lds_placement
GROUP BY fk1_account_id, fk3_job_role_id, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM plt_estimated_end_date)
)t
left join time_dim d
on t.year=d.year
order by t.fk1_account_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You have cleared my day-long headache. :)